# I can import CSV file with CSV option but doesnt work for CSV with LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql

I can import CSV file with CSV option but doesnt work for CSV with LOAD DATA. I get the error

```
Error: 1083 - Field separator argument is not what is expected
```

...although I am doing everything same,uploading the same file to same table.

Comment: This is a good question for http://superuser.com/ but not for here.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: What version of mySQL are you running? "LOAD LOCAL" has been phased out in some newer versions.

Comment: DevlshOne, what version are you referring to?  The docs for MySQL 5.7 have it and I don't see anything about `LOCAL` being deprecated.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Sometimes this issue can be caused by running this query using mysql -e"query here" and having ` ENCLOSED BY '"'` in the query.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably forgetting to set the field separator to a comma. Here's an example command for loading a CSV file from the [MySQL documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

> LOAD DATA INFILE can be used to read files obtained from external sources. For example, many programs can export data in comma-separated values (CSV) format, such that lines have fields separated by commas and enclosed within double quotation marks, with an initial line of column names. If the lines in such a file are terminated by carriage return/newline pairs, the statement shown here illustrates the field- and line-handling options you would use to load the file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Some notes:

- If your first row doesn't contain headers, you should omit the `IGNORE 1 LINES`.
- If your fields aren't enclosed by quotation marks, you can omit that too.
- Lastly, if your file is
  local, you should be using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.